# Django connect to MSSQL

Tags: django, pymssql

Hi I am trying to connect from django to mssql server. I installed

1 : `pip install django-mssql`

2 : `pip install pywin32`

after that i changed the database inside setting.py =>

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'TMSWEB',
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'HOST': '192.168.72.1\MSSQLSERVER5',
        'USER': 'sa',
        'PASSWORD': 'pwd',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server',
        }
    }
}
```

and then i check like that=>

2: `python manage.py makemigrations`

> django.db.utils.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver
>   specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

What i am still need to do? Please help me.

my django version : 2.1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of I don't have `ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server`. I download from [ODBC Driver 13 for sql server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) and installed. Its fixed. Thanks.